# Wi-Fi Adapter Not Found Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, troubleshooting

Wifi Adapter not found in recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.
Here is the script I just run (I tried to remove some sensitive data):
Can anyone help?

################################################################

EDIT:After trying everything I found on Internet:

1. Upgraded Kernels: 5.13, 6.0... nothing
2. Tried other drivers from a git...   nothing
3. Followed other instructions tried... nothing

I gave up after all day struggling with this, so I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04. The same problem appeared at first but I remembered a trick from the past that if i boot first with windows and reboot with Ubuntu the problem disappears! And it did actually!

So today I thought why I forgot trying this in Ubuntu 22.04? So I reinstalled today Ubuntu 22.04 and tried this and it seems to work!

In a nutshell If you have dual boot with windows and have tried everything with no luck, try booting from windows first then reboot to Ubuntu. Hope that helps somebody.

###################################################################

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Jan 2023 14:34 EET +0200

Booted last: 20 Jan 2023 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822be

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38b4]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:609c Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8822BE Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1249280  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
cfg80211              974848  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
wmi_bmof               16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
platform_profile       16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    32768  3 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
video                  61440  2 ideapad_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.2.9/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp8s0
       valid_lft 86028sec preferred_lft 86028sec
    inet6 2a02:85f:e05d:1300:5ecb:5853:9488:12c0/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86193sec preferred_lft 3393sec
    inet6 2a02:85f:e05d:1300:63db:47e:e820:b8aa/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86193sec preferred_lft 3393sec
    inet6 fe80::49ac:4ebc:a6ca:430/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp8s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp8s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.9 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         792       1  0 14:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp8s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-58-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.5/0000:08:00.0/net/enp8s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:08:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp8s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       b8ff6447-cd76-3d89-9753-6508acbdd599
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.2.9/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.2.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.2.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ???, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.2.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1674304099
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.2.9
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a02:85f:e05d:1300:5ecb:5853:9488:12c0/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         ???
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::49ac:4ebc:a6ca:430/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ???, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::1, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a02:858::8888
IP6.DNS[2]:                             ???
IP6.DNS[3]:                             fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2a02:858::8888 2a02:858::8844 fe80::1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   b8ff6447-cd76-3d89-9753-6508acbdd599 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp8s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp8s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    7.529244] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Down
[    9.017138] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[    9.017167] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp8s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 SecureBoot disabled!

Comment: Did you then reboot and did the wireless spring to life? If not, please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo modprobe rtw88_8822be && sudo dmesg | grep rtw88`

Comment: @chili555 No It didn't spring to life and the command you gave me return nothing.

Comment: How about: `sudo dmesg | grep 8822` Is this a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: Yes it is dual boot with Windows. At the moment I gave up after all day struggling with this and I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04. The same problem appeared at first but I remembered a trick from the past that ifi boot first with windows and reboot with Ubuntu the problem disappears!